# How to put two concat queries into the same table as two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I've just started using MySQL and I can't find the answer to this anywhere maybe because it doesn't exist?

I want to put these two together in one table as two columns

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ',Category) as Pet_Name_and_Category
FROM Animal

SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ',lastname) as Customer_Name
From PetCustomer
```

So the table I want would look something like:

```
Gary, Snail               Spongebob Squarepants

Sandy, Squirrel           Patrick Star
```

Where those are two separate columns in the same table.

Comment: How these two tables are related to each others?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` or `UNION`?

Comment: The two tables are not related to each other.  They are two separate tables.

Comment: I don't think I want either union or inner join.  I want only 2 columns created by 2 strings each from 2 different tables.

Comment: @user2045948 If the tables are not related, then you cannot have a proper join. Therefore, you cannot know the owner of each pet 'coz there is no relation between these two tables. If you want two columns, matching each pet to the owner, then you have to use a join and not an union.

Comment: Don't do this ! You're confusing data storage with data retrieval and display. -( I'm s little disappointed that others have failed to point this out )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select Name || ' ' || Category from Animal
union
select firstname || ' ' || lastname from PetCustomer;
```

If you want these as a separate column, then you can use this,

```
select Name || ' ' || Category as pet, firstname || ' ' || lastname as owner
from Animal, PetCustomer
where <join_condition_depending_on_table_structure>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), so something like:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(Name, ' ',Category) as Pet_Name_and_Category, 
    CONCAT(firstname, ' ',lastname) as Customer_Name
FROM Animal 
    INNER JOIN PetCustomer ON Animal.Customer_id = PetCustomer.id
```

The join syntax depends on how the 2 tables relate. With other words

> **How do you know that 'Spongebob Squarepants' owns 'Gary, Snail'?**

---

If they are not related and you just want to show them next to eachother, use 2 separate queries. *(example in PHP)*

```
$animals = $db->query("SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ',Category) as Pet_Name_and_Category FROM Animal");
$customers = $db->query("SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ',lastname) as Customer_Name From PetCustomer");

while (list($animal) = $animals->fetch_row() || list($customer) = $customers->fetch_row()) {
    echo $animal, "\t", $customer, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thought of this, but the OP mentions that the tables are not related. Therefore, the said join cannot be used.

Comment: @Orangecrush missed that, thanks for pointing it out. I've added an example for this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try subquery:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ',Category) 
     FROM Animal 
     WHERE <column> = <search_argument>)  as Pet_Name_and_Category ,
    (SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ',lastname) 
     FROM PetCustomer 
     WHERE <column> = <search_argument>) AS Customer_Name
FROM <first table>
```

Comment: This only works if the subqueries both return one row and can therefor not give the specified result.

Comment: Yes, subqueries can return only one result per row from main table. So there are WHERE condition in which you reference to actually row, that's why I put <search_argument>.

Comment: You can see that the example result has 2 rows, which is impossible with this query.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `CONCAT` twice for the same table, regardless of the condition, you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(TitleOfCourtesy, ' ', FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS NameEmployee, 
    CONCAT(PostalCode, ' ', Country, ' ', Region, ' ', City, ' ', [Address]) AS FullAddress
FROM Employees 
WHERE 1=1
```